# what is wrong with my factorial program ???

Tags: c

the output numbers are wrong why ?
the program is used to get factorial of a number using recursion
and if you know sites to practice more examples I will be thankful for you

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
int factorial(int a);
int main()
{
int n,x;
printf("enter ur number  ");
scanf("%d",&x);

n=factorial(x);

printf("the factorial = %d",n);



return 0;
}

int factorial(int a)
{
int fac;
if(a<=1)
{

if (a<1)
{

fac=0;
 }
return fac;
}

printf("the number = %d\n",a);

 printf("the factorial = %d\n",fac);

   fac = a * factorial(a-1);
```

Comment: indent your code. How can you write this and think the code is rightly written ?

Comment: There's at least one `}` missing. Also, is this your actual indentation? Also, `0!` is `1`, not `0`. Also, you have to  `return` the correct `fac`. I think there are least two lines missing, one of them being `}`, the other `return fac`. If that's true, then your error is the wrong base case. By the way, what ___IS___ wrong with your program? What do you expect, what do you observe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will always return 0, because the last fac will always be 0 and it multiplies all the other results. Change that to

```
if(a<1)
fac=1;
```

Also indent your code properly.